# count number of rows in database table

Tags: database

I have database table and it has couponcode. There is same coupon code for same product. I have made the limit on couponcode. When someone uses the couponcode, i want to delete the number from total coupon. lets say i have a table named socialcoupon and it has row named coupon code and total number of coupon. each time someone uses the coupon, it get stored in database but i want to be able to count how many coupon are used.

Comment: This is built in to Magento.  Go to Admin -> Reports -> Sales -> Coupons.

Comment: The coupon thing is i created, its custom coupon. and I need it to be displayed for users, not for myself. the number of coupon left is for my clients. I just need a php script that checks the used coupon and subtracts it from the total number of coupons

Comment: See: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10771/how-do-i-find-out-what-user-used-what-coupon-code